# Looking for Pasta Material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

Looking for [Pasta](https://ak.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/34899853/thumb/1.jpg) Material like this in **Cycles**.

[image]

I tried so far.

[image]

With this nodes.

[image]

With the basic knowledge of nodes i tried. Need more details. any suggestion or help how to make like a pro material. Thanks

Comment: maybe give it a bit Subsurface? You should also show a reference image to show what you want to achieve

Comment: @moonboots i tried but its getting black and i have attach reference image what im looking for

Comment: also try translucency?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a try for Eevee (a bit less al dente than your picture though), I guess the settings would be different for Cycles, and probably easier to find.

Use a *Principled BSDF* with a bit of *Subsurface Scattering* (don't forget to tweak the *Subsurface Radius* values), *Specular* at 1, a medium *Roughness*, and a bit of *Noise Texture* in order to have a bit of grainy texture:

[image]

For the pasta modeling:

- Create 2 circles, checker deselect the outter circle, scale down:

[image]

- Give it a *Screw* modifier to create a half torus:

[image]

- Close the tips with *LoopTools > Bridge*:

[image]

- Recalculate the normals, select the slots, bevel:

[image]

- Give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

- Deform it a bit with the *Proportional Editing* on...

Comment: Wow looks awesome how u created the lines or ridges on the surface.

Comment: Thanks Got this result. https://imgur.com/a/mYLwReY

Comment: maybe it needs to be worked a bit if you want them to look cooked (bot material and shape)

Comment: I was just going to say :).. crisp edges at the ends, where the pasta has been sliced on the way out of the die, look raw, and soft edges, cooked,

Comment: Perfectly rigid circles, and soft ends, is too uncanny valley for me.

Comment: Elles m'ont l'air trop cuites... mais bon... ; )

Comment: je sais, je les ai laissées 2 minutes de trop   :((  un peu trop glossy sans doute

Answer (score 6):

I find something like this works rather well, but this is for *my* lighting setup, so you may need to tweak it to look right in your scene.

The active element is Subsurface Scattering - a rather higher value than normal, but then again "normal" (default) values are designed for skin and not pasta. This will require some tweaking of the *Subsurface Radius* (RGB values) to make it more yellow in color (highlighted in the image below).

Aside from that some transmission works as well, but not too high a value, because the colors will become washed out - again, something to tweak with *your* lighting to find the right balance.

NOTE - the Wave texture is just there so I could see how the transmissive light passes through the "ridges" - use whatever (bump/normal) texture you like.

[image: Pasta]

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about the ridges on the pasta in the picture? I'd do that with a procedural texture.

Add a wave texture with a texture coordinate node attached, and fiddle with it until it applies to your pasta.

If you only need the texture to be apparent, feed it into a bump node and then into the Principled Shader's "Normal" slot.

If you really need the ridges, you can use a subsurface modifier on the bit of pasta and then apply actual displacement using the wave texture. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/components/displacement.html

Okay, then add a translucent shader and use a mix shader to blend the principled shader and translucent shader to output.

Or, and this might be easiest, you can just use subsurface scatter in the Principled Shader. Set the value to 1, the radius to 1, and the color to a nice yellow. Light will enter the pasta surface and move through it.

Comment: No im not looking for lines or ridges. Looking for the semi transparent material seen in the reference image